How to store files temporarily in ASP.NET Core?
I am generating QrCode PNG, just so I can upload them to AWS S3.
See code below:
var filePath = "my-qrcode.png";

QRCodeWriter.CreateQrCode(code, 500, QRCodeWriter.QrErrorCorrectionLevel.Medium)
    .SetMargins(30)
    .SaveAsPng(filePath);

S3Uploader.Upload(filePath);

The code works well, but the file my-qrcode.png is generated at the root of the application folder.
Is there a tmp folder for this scenario in ASP.NET Core ?

The result from QRCodeWriter.CreateQRCode also has a ToPngStream() overload which would return the image in a MemoryStream, thus enabling 'cutting out the middleman' of saving the file to the disk first. I think that might also be an interesting route to explore.

^^ since disc io is probably some orders of magnitude slower, I'd recommend exploring a pure in-mem solution.

Thanks @nbokmans. The S3 Library can work with a stream instead of a file path. So I just sent the stream from ToPngStream(). Thanks again.
